# What's the difference between these 2 solidity interfaces methods?

Tags: solidity, remix

I've been following a new journey into solidity for about a month now, so far so good, however with the Interface I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between these 2 methods of implementing Interfaces.

I can clearly notice how useful the Interface is in the 2nd method, but not in the 1st method.

Method 1:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ICounter {

    function count() external view returns (uint256);
    function addToCount() external;
}

contract myInterface is ICounter {

    uint256 counter = 0;

    function count() external view override returns (uint256) {
        return counter;
    }

    function addToCount() override external {
        counter++ ;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract myContract {
    uint256 count =0;

    function increment() external {
    count++ ;
    }
}
```

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ICounter {

    function count() external view returns (uint256);
    function increment() external;
}

contract myInterface {

    function incrementCount(address _counter) external {
        ICounter(_counter).increment();
    }

    function getCount(address _counter) external view returns (uint256) {
        return ICounter(_counter).count();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear, you are not using the interface on the second method, and whats the second screenshot for? Please add those details on the question

Comment: @JulissaDC Thank you for your time. In fact there's no screenshots, and the 2 methods are methods that I have crossed and tested so far for implementiing Interfaces. the 2nd Method is, a contract, and another contract casting from it through an Interface.

Answer (score 0):

The **method 1** is used when developing contract hierarchies and the interfaces might change. In this case inheritance enforces proper definitions in the implementations. A new method added or a change to the function parameters should trigger a compiler error.

The **method 2** is an important use cases for `Interface` in solidity. Interacting with already deployed contracts.

In order to write an exchange for NFTs a generic interface that will work with any NFT is the correct way to go. For example use IERC721 from OpenZeppelin.